# Racket: How to provide/require bindings only?

Tags: racket

In a file `add42.rkt` I have the following definition + effect:

```
#lang racket

(provide add42)

(define (add42 x)
  (+ x 42))

(displayln "-- add42.rkt --")
```

In a file `test.rkt`, I require + test:

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit "add42.rkt")

(check-equal? (add42 0) 42)
```

The test works fine, however, `-- add42.rkt --` is also displayed. Is there a way to *only* export the function definition from `add42.rkt`? (I thought `(provide add42)` would only do that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of. You can change `add42.rkt` so that the effects don't run when it is required by another module.

If you can reorganize `add42.rkt` so that the effects are all in a `main` submodule, then those effects will happen when `add42.rkt` is run by itself, but not when it is required into `test.rkt`.

In `add42.rkt` separate the effects into a `main` submodule with `module+ main`:

```
#lang racket

(provide add42)

(define (add42 x)
  (+ x 42))

(module+ main
  (displayln "-- add42.rkt --"))
```

The effects in the main submodule will be run after the other top-level expressions only if `add42.rkt` is being run as the main program, not required as a library.

Comment: That does it. Thank you!